# Copying a SQL Server table and adding and rearranging columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select-into

I know that if I want to make a copy of a SQL Server table, I can write a query akin to this:

```
SELECT * 
INTO NewTable
FROM OldTable
```

But what if I wanted to take the contents of `OldTable` that may look like this:

```
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
|---------|---------|---------|
| 1       | 2       | 3       |
| 4       | 5       | 6       |
| 7       | 8       | 9       |
```

and make a copy of that table but have the new table look like this:

```
| Column1   | Column3   | Column2   | Column4   | Column5   |
|---------  |---------  |---------  |---------  |---------  |
| 1         | 3         | 2         | 10        | 11        |
| 4         | 6         | 5         | 12        | 13        |
| 7         | 9         | 8         | 14        | 15        |
```

So now I've swapped Columns 2 and 3 and added Column 4 and Column 5. I don't need to have a query that will add that data to the columns, just the bare columns.

Comment: where are the numbers in `column4` and `column5` coming from?

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of modifying your select statement.  `SELECT *` takes only the columns from the source table, in their order.  You want something different - so `SELECT` it.

```
SELECT * INTO NewTable
  FROM OldTable
```

->

```
SELECT Col1, col3, col2, ' ' AS col4, ' ' AS col5
  INTO NewTable
  FROM OldTable
```

This gives you very little flexibility as far as how the table's columns are specced and indices and such - so it's probably a bad idea, probably better to do this another way (properly `CREATE TABLE`), but if you need quick and dirty, I suppose...

Comment: Obviously select NULL as col4/col5 if you want them numeric or specify them appropriately (within the limits of a SELECT specification).

Comment: How is `CREATE TABLE` better than this way? This gets all the old data straight into the table.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` has more options than this in terms of indices and keys and such.  As far as I know, anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You can just name the columns:

```
Select
[Column1], [Column3], [Column2], Cast(null as bigint) as [Column4], 0 as [Column5]
Into CopyTable
From YourTable
```

Just like any query, it is always preferable to use the Column names and avoid using `*`.

You can then add any value `as [ColumnX]` in the select.
You can use a cast to get the type you want in the new table.